# How to type in Mac window?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, keyboard, command-line

I want to enter a simple adb shell command, so I navigated to `...\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`, and opened it. However, I am unable to type in it!

[image]

I am a new Mac user after recently moving from Windows, and am unsure why I can't type in the adb. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Macs run *binaries* and not `.exe` files.

This `adb` is a binary, and must take options.

Open Terminal, from `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` and you should see something like this (colors should be different): [image: You should see something like this.]

Now, type in `adb` and press <kbd>return</kbd>. You should see the same output as you saw in your screenshot. Now, to run the command (the highlighted text in the background), copy (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) that text into the terminal window. Everything that follows `adb` are called "arguments", like modifiers that affect what the command does. This is quite common in shell commands.

```
   adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
  |-V-||---------------V-----------------|
 Command            Arguments
```

Alternatively, if you have a binary in a specific location, do: (`./` executes a binary)

```
cd /path/to/the/binary
./binary-name (arguments)
```

Side note: autocompletion can be very helpful in long directory names: by typing in a fragment of a name, then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>, autocompletion will fill in the rest of the fragment (assuming there are no similarly named items). Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice will show you what autocompletion can fill in.

```
$ cd /Users/Ha *presses tab*
$ cd /Users/Harry/

OR

$ cd /Users/H *presses tab twice*
Harry/ Henry/ Hagrid/
$ cd /Users/H
```

Comment: Hey, I really loved your descriptive answer. I navigated to my `platform-tools` directory, which contains my `adb.exe`, and tried to type in `adb` and `adb shell`. However, I got: `command not found`. What should I do? Here is a screenshot:

Comment: http://imgur.com/HkvFg4g

Comment: To run a binary, it is simply the name of the executable prepended by a `./`. In your case, that would be: `./adb shell`. Also, it is important to note that the executable inside that folder **is not a .exe file**, but rather a *binary*.

Comment: To attend to your "command not found" problem, that is due to the binary not being inside your `$PATH` directory, the paths that your computer looks in for binaries. Try `echo $PATH` in the Terminal, where you should see multiple paths. These paths are where commands should be placed to be called by just their name.  Try moving your `adb` binary into `/usr/local/bin` and just calling `adb` from the main command line.

Comment: I am unable to paste into `bin`: http://imgur.com/IRoPBO9

Comment: Make sure it's `/usr/local/bin`. Try Cmd+C Cmd+V instead of drag/drop.

Answer (score 4):

By clicking on a unix executable, you run it with the exit argument.  If you scroll up to the top you will see something like this:

```
.../Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb ; exit;
```

The way to run a shell tool is to open terminal (hit command+space and type Terminal then enter)
then something like:

```
cd /wherever/you/have installed/your sdk/platform-tools/
./adb shell
```

tip: start typing the directory name then hit tab for completion